# Can't find local SQL database from within Visual Studio in my ASP .NET MVC 4 project

Tags: visual-studio, entity-framework, visual-studio-2012

I have a project that uses EF 5 (code first) in Visual Studio 2012. When I build the database it works, but it isn't showing up in the SQL Explorer for some reason. I checked the connection object at runtime and I can see that the name of the local database is not listed in the SQL explorer. What's odd is that this project doesn't have this problem on another machine. The project is under source control

Comment: Similar problem but no source code control.

Comment: If you are using an `Instance` of `SQL Server 2012` try looking in `App_Data`. You have to click on show all files in Solution Explorer to see your Db file.

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if you have a running copy of Sql Server running.

I experienced the same thing; creating a project and then EntityFramework objects, and then running the project.  VS 2012 created the database in my 2008 R2 db which was running at the time, but I hadn't opened it in VS, so didn't see the new db.  It wasn't until I specifically opened that db in VS that it appeared.